# iOS - Audiounit volume balance between channel

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I created an AUGraph to play music from iTunes library. I added mixer unit and effect unit to the AUGraph in the following order

> FilePlayerUnit->MixerUnit->EffectUnit->OutputUnit

I am trying to change the volume balance between left and right channel. For example by using a UISlider user should be able change the frequency in a particular channel.

Is it possible to do this without modifying my current `AUGraph` based player with FilePlayer Unit that plays music files from local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You just need to set those properties on the input scope of the
>   desired channel(element).

```
float pan = 0;  //  -1  -> 1
AudioUnitSetParameter (MixerUnit, kMultiChannelMixerParam_Pan, kAudioUnitScope_Input, channel, pan, 0);
```

Got the above answer in the Core Audio mailing list. 
Thank you **Dave O'Neill**.

Comment: When I tried to set pan value, then I am getting below error:
*** AudioUnitSetParameter (Pan) error: 'fmt?'

Comment: can you post your code? Are you setting the value in the Mixer audio unit?

Comment: OSStatus resultPan = AudioUnitSetParameter (
                                                mixerUnit,
                                                kMultiChannelMixerParam_Pan,
                                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                                0,
                                                -1,
                                                0
                                                );
    
    if (noErr != resultPan) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitSetParameter (Pan)" withStatus: resultPan]; return;}

Comment: how do you create "mixerUnit", are you correctly setting audio component type(kAudioUnitType_Mixer) & subtype (kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer)

Comment: Yup, I have used kAudioUnitType_Mixer and kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer